# Safest way to change variable names in a project

Tags: c++, coding-style, refactoring, variable-names

So I've been working on a relatively large project by myself, and I've come to realise that some of the variable names earlier on were.. less than ideal.

But how does one change variable names in a project easily? Is there such a tool that can go through a project directory, parse all the files, and then replace the variable names to the desired one? It has to be smart enough to understand the language I imagine.

I was thinking of using regexp (sed/awk on linux?) tools to just replace the variable name, but there were many times where my particular variable is also included as a part of strings.

There's also the issue about changing stuff on a c++ namespace, because there is actually two classes in my project that share the same name, but are in different namespaces.

I remember visual studio being able to do this, but what's the safest and most elegant way to do this on linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Safest (non automated way) way:

1. Make sure all your unit tests work.
2. Save everything into source control.
3. Globally replace var with XXXvarXXX (seriously)
   a. Or maybe just the files you think need editing.
4. Try and compile. Everything that does not compile is easy to undo just remove the XXX.
5. When it compiles run the unit tests.
6. When the unit tests work. Do a global replace of XXXvarXXX to the new name.
7. Make sure the unit tests still work
8. Save everything in source control.

Tongue only half in cheek. :-)

Answer (score 6):

It's called refactoring, but I don't remember if there's a great way to do it in C++ -- I think maybe [Eclipse C++](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) had it; might be worth taking a look.

Comment: Eclipse CDT has it. QtCreator has it. Visual Studio has it. Visual Assist X for Visual Studio makes it even better. Vim has it. You got the point.

Comment: Ah Vim has it? Does it work for a multileveled project directory?

Answer (score 1):

> I remember visual stuio being able to do this, but what's the safest and most elegant way to do this on linux?

You can do pretty much what you used to do in visual studio in Eclipse using the re-factoring tools, which is available for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

$400 a f'n copy, but here you go: http://www.xref.sk/xrefactory/download.html

I've of course never used it.

Comment: Interesting, so that's how much one would charge for a tool which involved making a c++ parser?

Answer (score 0):

I know C# and visual studio has a great variable changer, but does it work through all the documents im not sure. I know when you change a variable in C# it pops up in the beside the Variable text. `Change All`

However you may be stuck with the only option. Change variables and see where the compiler goes wrong. However its not ideal, but may be your only choice

Comment: It's pretty far from ideal actually.  You could run into places that silently chose another variable because of scope.  I'd at least run a grep and TRY to separate them all.

Comment: yes you could do a shell script. Im sure i said its `not` ideal

Answer (score 0):

use private variables, rename the variable and the obvious uses, correct the compiler errors.