# How to replace all instances of a function call in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to replace all instances of '::memcpy()' with my custom made 'customMemcpy()' defined in a file 'Memory.h' in my project. This call is made from lot of places so doing it manually is pain. Is there any clever method to do it programmatically?

Comment: Whats wrong with Find and Replace?

Comment: It seems you have already got a 'method to do it problematically' :-(  Perhaps you want to do it programmatically, in which case perhaps your IDE (vi ?  Emacs ?  Notepad ?) can help.  Tell us what that is, we may be able to provide proper help rather than silly comments.

Comment: You could `#define memcpy customMemcpy`, assuming the parameters are the same.

Comment: Any text editing tool I know of (even ed) has a "Search&Replace" function. Why not use that?

Comment: Using Search and replace is not really good enough it can cause too many problems. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4665620/14065 In this case modify to change memcpy to XXXmemcpyXXX.

Comment: @LokiAstari: most IDE Search and Replace have an option for "Match entire word" that fixes that problem.

Comment: @MooingDuck: No IDE can not cope with the size of the code base I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wrapping mechanism, see http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html (find `--wrap=symbol`) for example. This way gives you acess both to your and original function.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name '*.cpp' -print0 | xargs -0 -l sed -i -e 's/\<memcpy\>/customMemcpy/'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#define memcpy(dst,src,size) custom_memcpy(dst, src, size)

void custom_memcpy(void* dst, const void* src, size_t size)
{
  //TODO: Implement Custom Memcpy
}
```